# Prove/Disprove Eigenvalues and eigenvectors - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given the following:

[image]

I'm stuck on $b,c,d$.

(b) I wrote the following:
$(A + IC)V = (λ + C)V \rightarrow AV + ICV = λV + CV$

And since $AV = λV \rightarrow ICV = CV $. So the statement is true.
Is this proof valid?

(c) I assume it is false, the diagonal matrix $D$ might have unique values but I can play with the entries, so different entries will result in a different matrix that is also conjugate to $A$. Is this true?

(d) I'm really not sure.. how does the algebraic multi and eigenvalues alone tell me that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), your conclusion is correct, but I'm not sure what you meant by the second line. Once you've shown $(A+cI)V = \lambda V + cV = (\lambda+c)V$, you are done, since that statement shows exactly that $\lambda+c$ is an eigenvalue of $A+cI$.

For (c), you are again correct. If you diagonalize the matrix by pre- and post-multiplying by its matrix of eigenvectors, the order you choose for the eigenvectors will determine the ordering of the eigenvalues down the diagonal of the result.

For (d), this statement is false. If the matrices have the same eigenvalues with multiplicity, and corresponding eigenspaces are the same, then they are similar. But for example,
$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
both have the multiple eigenvalue $2$, but one is diagonalizable and the other not, so they cannot be similar.

Comment: Great thanks, i can't seem to find a good counter example for c)
Can you help me with one?

Comment: Just find any 2x2 (say) matrix with distinct eigenvalues, and diagonalize it using both possible orderings of the normalized eigenvectors.